# Lambda doesn't create data in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

1. I get a code response 200 successful
2. but a null json message on Postman
3. Data is not created in DynamoDB. This is my lambda:

   ```
   exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {

    const id = replaceAll(event.queryStringParameters.authorId, " ", "-").toLowerCase();

    const params = {
        Item: {
            id: {
                S: id
            },
            title: {
                S: event.queryStringParameters.title
            },
            watchHref: {
                S: event.queryStringParameters.watchHref
            },
            authorId: {
                S: event.queryStringParameters.authorId
            },
            length: {
                S: event.queryStringParameters.length
            },
            category: {
                S: event.queryStringParameters.category
            }
        },
        TableName: "todos"
    };

    // console.log("@@@@@@@@@@@ ID " + params.Item.id.S + "");
    // console.log("@@@@@@@@@@@ Title " + params.Item.title.S + "");
    // console.log("@@@@@@@@@@@ Title " + params.Item.watchHref.S + "");
    // console.log("@@@@@@@@@@@ Title " + params.Item.authorId.S + "");
    // console.log("@@@@@@@@@@@ Title " + params.Item.length.S + "");
    // console.log("@@@@@@@@@@@ Title " + params.Item.category.S + "");


    dynamodb.putItem(params, function (err, data) {

        console.log("@@@@@@@@@@@ ID " + params.Item.id.S + "");

        if (err) {
            console.log("@@@@@@@@@@@ ERROR" + err);
            callback(err);
        } else {
            console.log("@@@@@@@@@@ INSIDE ELSE");
            callback(null, {
                id: params.Item.id.S,
                title: params.Item.title.S,
                watchHref: params.Item.watchHref.S,
                authorId: params.Item.authorId.S,
                length: params.Item.length.S,
                category: params.Item.category.S
            });
        }
    });
   };
   ```

What am I doing wrong? I folowed the same principles that on the documentation.

As a reference, I'm doing it with HTTP API gateway proxy integration and this is my table:

[image]

Comment: what is `replaceAll` ? should it be `event.queryStringParameters.authorId.replace(" ", "-").toLowerCase();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because you are using **async** function handler which finishes before you get any results. One way to overcome this is using a `Promise` pattern as shown in [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html#nodejs-handler-async).

Or maybe you don't want to use `async` handler at all. In this case you should remove `async` from your function and adjust the handler as shown in [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html#nodejs-handler-sync) for non-async handlers.

Comment: lol I just removed it and it worked, so I put the async because it makes sense to create the data and then handle whatever else is happening no? and thanks for the docs

Comment: @Arturo I don't have particular opinion/insight on that.